# Different format for Chapter in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I have changed the default table of contents format:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
```

the chapter now are no more in bold. Now I would like to have Table of Contents and Bibliography *bold* references :

```
 \tableofcontents
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bf{Bibliography}}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}
[...]
 \printbibliography
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bf{Bibliography}}
```

but this way the page number doesn't appear bold. How can I do to modify *just* the format of some voices?

## EDIT

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\begin{document}
 \frontmatter
 \tableofcontents
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bf{Contents}}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}
 \mainmatter
 \Blinddocument
 \backmatter
 \chapter*{Bibliography}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bf{Bibliography}}
\end{document}
```

In the PDF, in the table of contents "Contents" and "Bibliography" are bold but not their pagenumbers. I would like also the pagenumbers to be bold

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I edited the question including a MWE. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Shall any of the page numbers be bold?

Comment: No, only the page numbers corresponding to "Contents" and "Bibliography" in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Temporary changes to the style of the fonts in `ToC` should be written to the `ToC` itself with `\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\renewcommand{...}{...}}` etc.

I have defined a new command named `\addwithboldpagenumber` for this since there are two occurences of such additions, so there is some benefit of shorter code then.

Also don't use the deprecated command `\bf` but `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{0pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{1}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}

\newcommand{\addwithboldpagenumber}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappagefont}{\protect\bfseries}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bfseries#1}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}%
}


\begin{document}
 \frontmatter
 \tableofcontents
 \addwithboldpagenumber{\contentsname}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}
 \mainmatter
 \Blinddocument
 \backmatter
 \chapter*{\bibname}
 \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{\normalbaselineskip}}
 \addwithboldpagenumber{\bibname}
\end{document}
```

[image]